# PDFView doesn't update when adding PDFPage to the PDFDocument

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, pdfview, pdfpage

I'm making an application to scan multiple page pdf files. I have a `PDFView` and a `PDFThumbnailView` that are linked. The first time a scan is completed, I create a new `PDFDocument` and set it to `PDFView`. Then whenever another scan is completed I add a `PDFPage` to `[pdfView document]`.

Now the problem is whenever a page is added, neither the `PDFView` or `PDFThumbnailView` update to show the new document with the extra page. That is until I zoom in or out, then they both update to show the document with the new page.

The temporary solution I have now (zoom in and then autoscale) is certainly not the best one. Take for example when you have already zoomed in on the document, and you scan a new page, the view will then autoscale. I tried `[pdfView setNeedsDisplay:YES]` before but that doesn't seem to work.

This is the method where the scan arrives as `NSData`:

```
- (void)scannerDevice:(ICScannerDevice *)scanner didScanToURL:(NSURL *)url data:(NSData *)data {
    //Hide the progress bar
    [progressIndicator stopAnimation:nil];

    //Create a pdf page from the data
    NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    PDFPage *page = [[PDFPage alloc] initWithImage:image];

    //If the pdf view has a document
    if ([pdfView document]) {
        //Set the page number and add it to the document
        [page setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[pdfView document] pageCount] + 1] forKey:@"label"];
        [[pdfView document] insertPage:page atIndex:[[pdfView document] pageCount]];
    } else {
        //Create a new document and add the page
        [page setValue:@"1" forKey:@"label"];
        PDFDocument *document = [[PDFDocument alloc] init];
        [document insertPage:page atIndex:0];
        [pdfView setDocument:document];
    }

    //Force a redraw for the pdf view so the pages are shown properly
    [pdfView zoomIn:self];
    [pdfView setAutoScales:YES];
}
```

Does anyone know of a way where I can add a `PDFPage` and have the `PDFView` update without messing with the zoom state of the `PDFView`?

Comment: What happens if you just call [pdfView setNeedsDisplay:YES]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to manually call:

```
- (void)layoutDocumentView
```

I imagine the reason that this is not called manually is to allow coalescing of multiple changes into one update.

This is documented:

> The PDFView actually contains several subviews, such as the document
>   view (where the PDF is actually drawn) and a “matte view” (which may
>   appear as a gray area around the PDF content, depending on the
>   scaling). Changes to the PDF content may require changes to these
>   inner views, so you must call this method explicitly if you use PDF
>   Kit utility classes to add or remove a page, rotate a page, or perform
>   other operations affecting visible layout.
>
> This method is called automatically from PDFView methods that affect
>   the visible layout (such as setDocument:, setDisplayBox: or zoomIn:).

Comment: I upvoted with the hope that the answer would have worked, buy in my case (macOS 10.12) I am not able to display the annotations I have just drawn

Comment: Did you get the solution to your problem. These problems seem to continue in the latest release of PDFKit.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I got so far to refresh manually the PDFView with annotation was to move the PDFView to another page and come back to the page you need to refresh because:

`- (void)layoutDocumentView` didn't work for me in my case.

Then:

```
[self.pdfView goToLastPage:nil];
[self.pdfView goToPage:destinationPage];
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. But this wont set the exact offset, how did you manage that.